# flexdashboard .storyboard Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

How to add a reactive variable into storyboard?
My code below

````
---
title: "Storyboard Page"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
runtime: shiny
---

```{r}
x<-reactive({input$slider1})

```

Analysis {.storyboard}
=========================================

### Frame 1 `r x`

```{r}
sliderInput("slider1", label = h3("Slider"), min = 0, 
        max = 100, value = 50)
```
````

**The output**

[image: Now I have]

**The required**

[image: Expected result]

Comment: Looks like a little bug